# C++ two arrays with some duplicate data

Tags: c++, arrays

I'm working on N-body simulations in C++, I have collected all particles together using an array of a particle class. I need to work on sub-collections of particles separately, perhaps in a new array, but would still like to keep the full collection at the same time.

I already have code which takes an array of particles and acts on them, so ideally I'd like to just make new sub arrays pointing to the same data. Is there a good (neat, and efficient) way to define a sub-array pointing to the same memory as the main array of all the particles?

For example:

```
particle *full = new particle [10];
// define full here

particle *sub = // last 5 entries of full

func(full); // work on whole collection
func(sub); // work on sub collection
func(full); // work on whole collection with changes on sub[]
```

I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13576160/is-there-a-way-in-c-to-get-a-sub-array-from-an-array) about working on sub arrays which isn't really what I want to do.

Any suggestions would be fantastic, this is my first large-ish project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In C++ I'd use vectors instead of arrays (personal taste).

so

```
vector<particle> full;
//fill in `full`
vector<particle*> sub;
for(unsigned i=0;i<5;i++) if(full.size()>5-i) sub.push_back(&full[i]);
```

Now you have two vectors, sub's elements being pointers to full's elements

Answer (score 0):

You may pass size to your method, and then:

```
particle *full = new particle [10];
// define full here

particle *sub = full + (10 - 5);// last 5 entries of full

func(full, 10); // work on whole collection
func(sub, 5); // work on sub collection
func(full, 10); // work on whole collection with changes on sub[]

delete[] full;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using memcpy

```
void * memcpy ( void * destination, const void * source, size_t num );
```

Just pass the source arg as full+5, sizeof(particle) as size_t num and destination as the new pointer. From there they should be independent.

EDIT:

Use @Jarod42 approach if you want just a reference to the array instead of a whole copy