# (C++) How to obtain sub-array from an array WITHOUT nested loops?

Tags: c++, arrays, nested-loops

Still a beginner to coding, but is there a way to obtain sub-array from an array without the use of nested loops i.e. more traditional methods?

Comment: Being a beginner is fine. Asking a coding question without including a sample of the problem you're trying to solve is not. It's like visiting the mechanic about a car problem but forgetting to bring your car. Please edit your question to include any relevant code, ideally in the most minimal form that conveys the specific problem.

Comment: I'm also confused by what you mean by *"more traditional methods"* - IMO loops are one of the most traditional things in programming.

Comment: When you say "array" do you mean an old C-style array? When you say "sub-array" what do you mean by that? Why not simply have a pair of indexes (beginning and end)? Or a pair of iterators?

Comment: You should use iterators, check out this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13576160/is-there-a-way-in-c-to-get-a-sub-array-from-an-array

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want a copy of a part of a vector, you can use a constructor that takes an interator for the beginning and the end of the new vector.

```
vector<int> array = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
vector<int> subArray(array.cbegin() + 2, array.cbegin() + 4);

for (int i : subArray) {
    cout << i << endl;
}
```

output:

```
2
3
```

Comment: OP never mentioned vectors

Comment: The question is too vague to know. Vectors are one of the more classic C++ ways to handle arrays. If the question is updated and it turns out that OP means bare C arrays, std::array, or a pointer I will duly delete my answer.