# Is there a way to index an array in c++, like in python?

Tags: c++11

In order to write a packet sniffer I need to be able to index through the bytes of the packet.

I have come from python, in python you can index through a list very easily eg;

```
variable = data[2:5]. In c++ you can't do it like that.
```

---

Here is a snippet of my code

```
void ethernet_frame(char raw_data[19]){

    struct ethernet{ 
        char dest_mac[6] = get_mac_addr(raw_data[:7]);
        char src_mac[6] = get_mac_addr(raw_data[7:14]);
        unsigned short proto  = proto[14:17]; 
    };
}
```

I expect that there is an alternative or perhaps a library I can use to index through the packet.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way in C++ to get a sub array from an array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13576160/is-there-a-way-in-c-to-get-a-sub-array-from-an-array)

Comment: This is called a "slice" in Python.

Comment: you can use `std::copy`/`memcpy` in this case

Answer (score 2):

There's no built-in way of doing this, but C++ allows you to create abstractions to achieve your goals. E.g.

```
void ethernet_frame(std::array<char, 19> raw_data)
{
    struct ethernet
    {
        std::array<char, 6> dest_mac;
        std::array<char, 6> src_mac;
    };

    ethernet e{slice<0, 7>(raw_data), slice<7, 14>(raw_data)};
}
```

Where `slice` is something along the lines of:

```
template <std::size_t Begin, std::size_t End, typename T>
auto slice(const T& range)
{
    constexpr auto count = End - Begin - 1;
    std::array<std::decay_t<decltype(*range.begin())>, count> result;
    std::copy(range.begin() + Begin, range.begin() + End, result.begin());
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

C++ is not Python. So you cannot code like this.

You might want to use pointer arithmetic (e.g. `raw_data+7` if `raw_data` is some `char*`)

You could use [iterators](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator) and [range for](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for). Then you want to use [containers](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container) like `std::array` or `std::vector`

Please take several days or weeks to read a good [C++ programming book](http://stroustrup.com/Programming/). We don't have time or space for that here.